# Allow html input box to only enter one full number and exactly decimal .5

Tags: javascript, html, onkeypress

I'm making web application that requires users to enter number with one decimal place. I restrict users from entering other characters that numbers from using this javascript code

html

```
<input type="number" name='days' class="w3-input w3-padding-tiny" id="cntday"  onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" placeholder="Enter days"/>
```

javascript

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 &&
             (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
             return false;
          return true;
         }
```

but this function only prevent users from entering characters other than numbers.
I need to prevent users from entering more than one decimal places as well as entered decimal should be .5

it's like this

- if user enter 5.55 it should replace with  5.5 OR prevent user to input additional decimal
- and if user enter 5.2 OR any decimal it should be replace with 5.5 in other words users should only able to enter number with decimal .5

how can I achieve this with my current onkeypress function ?

This is NOT a duplicate of the other question. Stop flagging this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by split the number into two parts:

<kbd>Part 1</kbd> for natural number.

<kbd>Part 2</kbd> for decimal number.

then you can replace any entered decimal number to `.5`

*Something like this:*

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
var value = this.value;
var pos = value.indexOf(".");
var result;
if (pos !== -1) {
    var part1 = value.substr(0, pos);
    var part2 = value.substr(pos);
    result = part1 + part2.replace(part2,".5")
    $('input').val(result);
}
});

function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 &&
        (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
        return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name='days' class="w3-input w3-padding-tiny" id="cntday"  onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" placeholder="Enter days"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$('#cntday').keyup(function() {
    if(this.value %1 != 0.5){
        this.value = this.value - this.value%1 + 0.5;
    }
});
```

The condition checks whether a decimal has been entered or not and as soon as a decimal is entered and a number is entered it changes it to .5 
It fulfills both the requirements you mentioned.
Check it here https://jsfiddle.net/xn0koawx/